# Get context inside an SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-context, android-syncadapter

I am building a custom `MySyncAdapter` based heavily on the one in [the guide](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html). Inside the sync action, I want to get a preference from `SharedPreferences`, however `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` needs a `context`, and I cannot get one with any of the common methods:

- `this`
- `MainActivity.this`
- `getApplicationContext()`

How do I get a `context` inside the `SyncAdapter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SyncAdapter` does actually get a context from outside, just not in the sync method:

`public MySyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize)`

In the constructor, I just need to assign `context` to `this.mContext` which can be referenced in the sync method.